# MySQL insert data from file to table which starts from specific line

Tags: mysql, import

I have an SQL table and it contains columns

```
 a    b    c    d
---  ---  ---  ---
int  int  null null
```

I want to insert data from a .txt or .csv file into columns (c,d) of the table. But I **don't** want to start inserting from first line of the text file because my text (or .csv) file looks like:

```
age  weight height
 12    45    151
 23    73    174
```

the fisrt line in my .csv file includes labels (age,weight,height)(e.g.)
How can I import my data to selected columns?

Comment: why u don't want to start inserting from first line..for more clearance can u give one eg..

Comment: you dont want to start from first line - does that means that you want to start from second line everytime? Is it fixed that you want to start from second line?

Comment: yes, only one time I will run it and I want to avoid first line. I will start recording from 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

Using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html), you can specify how many lines you want to skip.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc.csv'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Please check-out below mentioned URL for detailed information.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Comment: It was really an impressive answer. Even i didnt knew this. I tried to figure out detailed information when i read your answer. So, i have added link here too hoping that JoshuajeanThree might also need it. Thanks.

Comment: I already had the link on the LOAD DATA INFILE on the first line, but I admit they are a bit hard to see!

Comment: Oh yes. I am sorry for that. Thanks anyways for the answer and the reply as well.